# How to pass states here?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state

I have a component `ModifyWordPartButton` that has a state `isHovered` and a child `IconButton`. `IconButton` `onclick` that is a child of another component, `SelectWordPartToModify`, that has a method `handleClickOpen()`. `IconButton` is supposed to be able to have its `onClick` = `SelectWordPartToModify`'s `handleClickOpen()`.

When using this code:

`ModifyWordPartButton`:

```
.
.
.
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton className={this.state.isHovered ? 'hoveredClass' : null />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`SelectWordPartToModify`:

```
.
.
.
render() {
    <ModifyWordPartButton />
}
```

results in `IconButton` inheritng `ModifyWordPartButton`'s `isHovered` state but not inheriting `SelectWordPartToModify`'s `handleClickOpen()`.

And when I use this code:
`ModifyWordPartButton`:

```
.
.
.
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`SelectWordPartToModify`:

```
.
.
.
render() {
  <ModifyWordPartButton onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
    <IconButton onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
  </ModifyWordPartButton
}
```

`IconButton` doesn't inherit `ModifyWordPartButton`'s `isHovered` state.

I tried in `ModifyWordPartButton`'s `render()` to replace `this.props.children` with:

```
this.props.children.map(
  child => {
    React.cloneElement(child, this.state)
  }
)
```

but React gave me an error about not recognizing `IconButton`'s `isHovered` property.

Here's the full code I use:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zwlz41mo93?codemirror=1&eslint=1&fontsize=14

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't fully understand your question, but.. Can't you pass more than one props to `IconButton`? Something like the following:

`SelectWordPartToModify`

```
render() {
    return <ModifyWordPart handleClick={this.handleClickOpen} />
}
```

`ModifyWordPart`

```
render() {
    return (
        <IconButton
            className={this.state.isHovered ? 'hoveredClass' : null}
            handleClick={this.props.handleClick} />
    );
}
```

This way, `handleClickOpen` must be defined in `SelectWordPartToModify`, and can be executed inside `IconButton` using `this.props.handleClick()`. Moreover, you also have the `className` of `IconButton` based on the `isHovered` property of `ModifyTwoPart`

---

**EDIT:** Regarding your sandbox:

1. At line 78 of `ModifyWordPartButton` you should not write `handleClickOpen={this.handleClickOpen}` but instead `onClick={this.handleClickOpen}`: being a `div` a simple DOM element, you cannot pass to it property like a your own Component.
2. At line 71 of the same file, again, you should use `onClick` instead of `handleClickOpen`: `IconButton` is indeed a Component, but it belongs with Material UI and it seems to expect an `onClick` props.
3. Moreover, in both lines you should not write `this.handleClickOpen`, but instead `this.props.handleClickOpen`, because the function is passed to `ModifyWordPartButton` using the props!
4. I guess the `IconButton` at line 60-68 of `SelectSuffixToModify` can be deleted without any ripercussion (if I guest right what you wanted to do, then it is not useful at all keeping it there).

I've forked your sandCodebox, here it goes → https://codesandbox.io/s/6wxj4nyn6z I think it does what you asked for.

Though, I think you need some clarification because, based on what you wrote, I think you have some confusion in your mind. When you write your own Component, you can make them expecting the props you want: in your example, `ModifyWordPartButton` is your own Component and you created him in a way that expect a prop named `handleClickOpen`; thus, when you call it from the `SelectSuffixToModify` `render()` method, you can pass it a function using `handleClickOpen={...}`.

Instead, `IconButton` is made from someone else, thus you should be aware of what are its props! Information which I guess you can find it on the official documentation of material UI :)

Comment: What I meant that `IconButton` is supposed to inherit both `isHovered` from `ModifyWordPart` and `handleClickOpen` from `SelectWordPartToModify`.

I tried what you suggested and it did not work. I've no idea why, because it seemed to me like it should work.

Comment: Also, I edited the question - wherever I referred to a component "ModifyWordPart" I meant "ModifyWordPartButton" (it's one component, not two separate ones).

Also, I added a link to the full code I use.

Comment: I've edited the answer.. Take a look, it should be resolved

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The code worked with a tiny modification to adjust it to work exactly how I wanted, and thank you for the explanations, as well - I'm still new to React so it was useful.